# How to override stopwords in lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing, stop-words

I am creating a Lucene index in my folder and I'm indexing the content of txt files. I want my content without stopwords indexing, but after passing through the analyzer actually put me off the stopwords when searching, but I all text indexes.
I put the code below:

```
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(new SimpleFSDirectory(indexDir),
                        new SpanishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36),
                        create,
                        IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    if (!file.isHidden() && file.exists() && file.canRead()) {


                String fileName = file.getName();
                String type = Files.extension(file);
                if(type==null)
                {
                    type="";
                }
                Document d = new Document();

                d.add(new Field("Name",fileName,
                                Store.YES,Index.ANALYZED,Field.TermVector.YES));
                d.add(new Field("Type",type,
                                Store.YES,Index.ANALYZED));
                if(("txt".equals(type.toLowerCase())) || ("log".equals(type.toLowerCase())))
                {
                    String Content = Files.readFromFile(file,"ASCII");
        d.add(new Field("Content",Content,Store.YES,Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
                }
    }

    writer.addDocument(d);
```

The contents of a sample file is "of a to install a directory". If I perform a search for "a", "to", "of" I do not find anything, it means that I have successfully passed the analyzer.
Using the tool to see the index LUKE, I see that the field contains "to install to a directory of", but seeing the look Field.TermVector containing: "install" and "directory" only, and that's all I want to appear in the field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a default constructor of SpanishAnalyzer(). You should use the one [with stop words as argument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/es/SpanishAnalyzer.html#SpanishAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.util.Version,%20java.util.Set%29).

Create your indexer as below:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(new SimpleFSDirectory(indexDir),
                    new SpanishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, new HashSet<String>()),
                    create,
                    IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

Here we are passing an empty set of stop words, hence overriding defaults with no stopwords. You should read more about [lucene stop-words](http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2009/05/27/lucene-search-ignore-word-list/) here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different constructor for `SpanishAnalyzer`: instead of

`new SpanishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36)`
use
`new SpanishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, Collections.emptySet())`

Comment: I just try and i indexes the content exactly as before.